# How to deny upload in proftpd

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

I have the directory: /home/ftp/download.

I would like to allow only downloading from this directory i proftpd.

I used the following config but it doesn't work:

```
<Directory /home/ftp/download/>
   <Limit STOR STOU>
       DenyAll
   </Limit>    
</Directory>
```

STOR = (Transfer a file from the client to the server)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run sftp and not ftp.

sftp runs by openssh.

ftp runs by proftpd.

The changes didn't take effect because I run sftp and not ftp in the ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your other config and file permissions are correctly mapped, this should allow to download, but no upload.

```
Directory /home/ftp/download/>
    <Limit READ>
       AllowAll
   </Limit>    
   <Limit STOR STOU>
       DenyAll
   </Limit>    
</Directory>
```

Comment: No! I can still upload files to /home/ftp/download. Maybe a need to chmod /download with a specific way.

Comment: what if you change the order?

Comment: No difference. It doesn't work because maybe i am using FTP+SSL, SFTP.

Comment: And if you try to add `WRITE` in block `<Limit STOR STOU WRITE>DenyAll</Limit>` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Can you pastebin the config? It is hard to troubleshoot something so blindly.

Comment: What do you mean by pastebin?

Comment: just paste the config to some online paste tool http://pastbin.ca for exmaple, remove all security related info and then paste the link what pastebin.ca will give you.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/Kf1xU6Z2

Comment: Ok, so with <Limit STOR> DenyAll </Limit> you still are able to upload? Also what if you remove slash after "download" like            "<Directory /home/ftp/download>"?

Comment: Doesn't matter.